# Logic App not picking up all messages from queue

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azureservicebus

I have a azure service bus queue which has a number of message's within it.  And have a logic-app using a manual trigger. I then add a "Get messages from a queue (peek-lock)" action to the app to get the messages from this service bus and set the maximum message count to "170". But when it's triggered it only picks 1 message. Can someone explain why this is. And why it's not picking up 170 messages.

Thanks

Comment: Screenshots?!? Provide more info please. Hard to help when we’re blind.

Answer (score 1):

Use SB property in Logic APP

Property name :Maximum message count
maxMessageCount =>  integer

The maximum number of messages to return in the batch

Answer (score 0):

- You can use the [auto-complete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-servicebus#add-service-bus-trigger) trigger which will help you in getting Messages one after the other.

> Some triggers, such as the **When one or more messages arrive in a queue (auto-complete)** trigger, can return one or more messages. When these triggers fire, they return between one and the number of messages that's specified by the trigger's **Maximum message count** property.

- You can reverfiy your logic app with the help of this [Microsoft Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/paolos/service-bus-explorer-2-6-now-available).